# How to list all clickable links in a website using selenium, python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium. I want to navigate to [www.cisco.com](http://www.cisco.com) and list all the clickable buttons by their names (and respective xpaths too if possible) in a list like

['Log in','Products and services','Solutions',....etc. ]

I can navigate to the site using a chrome browser exe as given below :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
chromedriver_location = "C:\\Path\\To\\chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_location)
driver.get('https://cisco.com/')

first_popup_close='//*[@id="onetrust-close-btn-container"]/button'
supposedly_front_page='//*[@id="wcq"]'
#Close the pop-up
driver.find_element("xpath", first_popup_close).click()

#If I am not wrong in selecting the XPATH..
ids = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, supposedly_front_page)

for i in ids:
    #print i.tag_name
    print(i.get_attribute("name"))    # Does not work as expected
```

I even tried using `find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Log in")`,`find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Log")`etc. just to find only the 'Log in' button (in case my front page XPATH may be wrong), but it does not return the output (empty list).
The issue is - selenium doc has vague information about such or may be I am not able to find the required info. The older posts about the same does not work mostly as lots of functions have been deprecated by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to get the login button for example from this page do:

```
loginbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='fwt-profile-button']")
```

or if you'd like to get all buttons you can identify them by doing:

```
btns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button")
```

Comment: Please specifiy, on if you'd like to get all HTML button elements or HTML link elements.

Comment: You can use Chrome/Firefox Plugins like XPath selector to do the job for you. They will highlight which current button/s is/are going to be affected by your query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! yes it works. However the `find_element_by_xpath` has been deprecated. So i used `find_elements(By.XPATH,"//button")`. It lists the following 
ProductsCDCR, Products, SolutionsCDCR, Support, SupportCDCR, LearnCDCR, Partners, fwt-nav-button...However wondering what we can do to also obtain the 'Log in' button name?

Comment: how to obtain HTML link elements as well?

Comment: As we speaking. If you need to get a specific attribute from the buttons you can put a `.get_attribute('id')` behind your `find_elements(By.XPATH,"//button")` . If you're simply searching for the inner name do `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` .

Comment: I can get the login button name from its respective xpath. Actually my motive is to automate the process of obtaining new things in a website. So even if I dont have access to the "xpaths" or i dont know what new things are been added, is it possible to list them ?

Comment: Do `find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a").get_attribute('href')` to get all link urls from the HTML a object of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247290/discussion-between-mrin9san-and-dotolox).